# How to combine strings in R with the `+` sign?

Tags: r, string, if-statement

I have an if statment, that if an argument that is passed to the function, called `case`, is longer than 1, then the first colname of the data frame would be the combination of the first two values of `case`:

```
  for(i in 1:length(case)){
    if (length(case) > 1){
      colnames(scores)[1] = case[[i]] + case[[i+1]]
    } else {
      colnames(scores)[1] = case  
      
    }
  }
```

the problem is with the `case[[i]] + case[[i+1]]` part. In python, for example, if you do `a` + `b`, the result would be `ab`. Here I don't know how to do that. All I want is that if the condition above is `TRUE`, the first column of `scores` would become `case[[i]] + case[[i+1]]`.

`case` is just a vector that contains strings, like this `case = c('CR','PD')`. Sometimes I pass it with one value, sometimes more. In my case here I want the first column of `scores` to be `CRPD` or something like that.

If I tried the code above, I get this error, and that is of course because `CR` and `PD` are strings and here this won't work like in python:

```
Error in case[[i]] + case[[i + 1]] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: Can you please make your question reproducible?

Comment: you will have to use paste , should the colname only be case 1 and case 2 or would it be case ...n ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

First, `+` isn’t overloaded for string concatenation in R as it is in Python. Instead, use [`paste()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/paste) (default separator = `" "`) or `paste0()` (separator = `""`). e.g., `paste0(case[[i]], case[[i+1]])`.

Second, your `for` loop doesn’t make sense, and isn’t needed if I understand your goal. As written, it overwrites the first column name on each iteration, and on the last iteration, `case[[i + 1]]` tries to access an index one greater than the total length of the vector, which by definition doesn’t exist.

Using `paste0()` and ditching the `for` loop:

```
if (length(case) > 1) {
  colnames(scores)[1] <- paste0(case[[1]], case[[2]])
} else {
  colnames(scores)[1] <- case
}

head(scores)
```

```
      CRPD Gender treatment Cancer_Type CD4-T-cells
Pt1     PD   male  anti-PD1    Melanoma -0.07410987
Pt10    SD female  anti-PD1    Melanoma -0.09440127
Pt101   PR female  anti-PD1    Melanoma  0.04102849
Pt103   PD female  anti-PD1    Melanoma -0.16330295
Pt106   PD   male  anti-PD1    Melanoma -0.09424782
Pt11    PD female  anti-PD1    Melanoma -0.16731441
```

If your goal is to concatenate *all* elements of `case` regardless of length, you can get rid of the `if` statement too and just do:

```
colnames(scores)[1] <- paste0(case, collapse = "")
```